# How to display textbox's inside a div on a button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `div` and I want to display two textbox inside the `div` on a button click event. Is it possible achieve without using `script`?

Comment: Yes It's possible. Give id to <div> and add runat="server". so <div> will be accessible in code behind.

Comment: @RahulNikate:can you please provide me the codes or examples?

Comment: Should have given more information on whether you wanted to add the textbox dynamically or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let `<div id="myDiv" runat="server"></div>` be your div. add the following code in button click for include two text boxes.

```
 myDiv.InnerHtml = "<input type='text' name='name' value='first Text'/><input type='text' name='name' value='first Text'/> ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `id` to `<div>` and add `runat="server"`

```
<div id="dvPanel" runat="server"></div>
```

Then add below code in you button click event

```
dvPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID = "txtBox1" });
dvPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID = "txtBox2" });
```

Answer (score 0):

**design time**

<div id="example1" class="t1">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt01" runat="server" Width="240px" MaxLength="50" height="20px;"></asp:TextBox> 
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt02" runat="server" Width="240px" MaxLength="50" height="20px;"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

-----  **on button click**

example1.Attributes["class"] = "t2";

--------------
**css class**

t1 
 .height:1px;
 .overflow:hidden;

t2
 .height:80px;
 .overflow:hidden;